# Decrypt VIM encrypted file in Python

Tags: python, vim, encryption

In my Python web app, I would need to decrypt a file that was encrypted using VIM. Assuming the web app knows the password used to encrypt the file in VIM, how do I write code to decrypt ?

Comment: So how was it encrypted, in VIM or Python? What method was used?

Comment: It was encrypted in VIM using "vim -x". But I want to decrypt it using Python (as the Python program will run on Google App Engine). (edited the question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that vim uses the same encryption as PKZIP:

```
from zipfile import _ZipDecrypter

fp = open(somefile, 'rb')
zd = _ZipDecrypter(somekey)

fp.read(12)
print ''.join(zd(c) for c in fp.read())

fp.close()
```

Comment: Unfortunately `_ZipDecrypter` is not available in App Engine (or Python 2.5)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tool to do exactly that, also supporting the more recent encryption methods:

https://github.com/nlitsme/vimdecrypt

Answer (score 0):

The python3 version:

```
from pathlib import Path

from zipfile import _ZipDecrypter

print(_ZipDecrypter(b"<password>")(Path(r"<path>").read_bytes()[12:]).decode("utf8"))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, just get jumble of undecodable bytes.